# What is the difference between a hypothesis test of $P(|Z|\geq z)$ versus $P(|Z|\geq |z|)$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

For a Z test, in say a Normal Z test with known variance, what is the difference between rejection areas being represented by

$P(|Z|\geq z)$

versus

$P(|Z|\geq |z|)$

For $P(|Z|\geq z)$, the rejection regions seem to correspond to the sets $Z\geq z$ and $Z\leq z$. What about when $P(|Z|\geq |z|)$?

Comment: Do not forget $P(Z \ge |z|)$ while you are at it! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you have chosen $z$ to be a positive number, there is no difference between the two tests and the *description* of the rejection region as the set
$$\{Z \geq z\}\cup \{Z \leq -z\}.\tag{1}$$
Note that what you have *stated* in your question as the rejection region is missing a $-$ sign.

But if you have chosen $z$ to be a negative number, then you need to describe the rejection region as
$$\{Z \geq |z|\}\cup \{Z \leq -|z|\}.\tag{2}$$
Since $(2)$ is the same as $(1)$ when $z>0$, *you* should always use $(2)$ to describe the rejection region so that *you* never need be confused.

Comment: Sidenote: A negative $z$ is not very useful. If $z$ is negative, and since $|Z|$ is always positive, then $P(|Z| > z) = 1$.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I agree that if $z < 0$, then the hypothesis $|Z| < z$ will always be rejected. But the OP never talked about testing $|Z| < z$ when $z < 0$; only about $|Z| \geq |z|$ and so that's the only case I considered.